# too much text for a slide: how to get all smaller

Tags: r-markdown, beamer

I am trying to make a very simple presentation with Rmarkdown, no chunks involved. I would like to have quite a lot of text, so things got not printed because they are off limits.

Isn't there an option that beamer will set the size of the text such that all the text is visible, or at least a quick way to make the text smaller by hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the text of some slides smaller, you could wrap it in a `small` (or `tiny` or `footnotesize`) environment:

```
---
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes:
- \newcommand{\bsmall}{\begin{small}}
- \newcommand{\esmall}{\end{small}}
---

## Normal slide

slide text 

## Small slide

\bsmall
Slide text
\esmall
```

Cf. [this question on tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/how-to-change-font-size-mid-document)

Comment: this command is great, however, it overwrites other commands: for instance `\begin{small} - **this is a bullet point in bold** \end{small}` does not show up as it should. Do you know how I can use all the usual feature but using reduced size/

Comment: @Alessandro pandoc ignores markdown code between \begin{} and \end{} latex markes. That is why you need to first redefine the commands. "\bsmall **bold text** \esmall" should work.

Comment: For me, the proposed solution somehow only worked if I added it to the `beamerthemeNAME.sty`or `preamble.tex`, but not via `header-includes".